# "No network devices available"

Tags: networking

"No network devices available"
Just installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS onto my laptop, hp stream. When i check the network connections icon on the taskbar, i get the message "No network devices available". Even some of the language package did not install completley because of no internet conection.

(I've had internet connected on this computer with ubuntu before, but it was unstable off and on, and no is gone, and I've come to a point where everything is re-booted).

I have no ethernet cable plug in my computer.

when i write "lspci" in the terminal, i get this below as output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
```

I really hope someone can help me.

Comment: This is a hardware issue.

Comment: It seems that the kernel isn't even detecting the wireless card. You don't have a USB Wi-Fi dongle, right?

Comment: this is why ubuntu comes with a try option prior to install - to check needed devices are working (hardware recognized & works).  your list.pci.devices (lspci) reveals no kernel recognized wireless device.  the linux kernel allows more modules (drivers) to be added; but the kernel you've got doesn't have whatever is required (assuming your hardware is working).  without exact details on chipsets (not model of laptop, but chips enclosed as they vary) i can't help you.  you could try other live (distros, or versions) and when you get wireless recognized; note the module needed, then add to 16.04

Comment: This is a "Bay Trail" and the result is expected because the WiFi runs on a SDIO bus. There are special Ubuntu images for that hardware where most, not all, devices are properly detected.